# WPF TextBox BorderBrush Style vs. No Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why does a border appear around a TextBox when a Style is used as opposed to no Style being used? Is there a way to set this using a Style so no border appears, like in the "Phone" Grid/TextBox? See below:

[image]

**WINDOW XAML**

```
    <!-- City, State, Zip -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" Margin="50,2,25,2">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBox Style="{Binding StandardTextBox1}" Text="{Binding CityStateZip}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Phone -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Background="White" Margin="50,2,25,2">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBox
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderBrush="Transparent"
                 Text="{Binding FacilityPhoneMain}"
                 TextAlignment="Center"
                 FontSize="14"
                 />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

**STYLE XAML**

```
<!-- Standard TextBox 1 -->
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="StandardTextBox1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your textbox is at fault? Do you have any Visual Tree inspection tool at hand (like Snoop, or some recent Visual Studio versions have this ability). You should probably just select the unexpected rectangle at runtime and check the value source for the borderbrush.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `BorderThickness` property of the `TextBox` in your Style to remove the border.

As for why the border is not affected in the Style, I have a hunch that this is due to dependency property precedence.

Animations have a higher precedence than property setters. Due to the default WPF Textbox template having animations that affect the `BorderBrush` property, the setters are not being applied.

[This link has some relevant information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796916/wpf-the-style-of-control-does-not-work-unless-the-control-template-created-for)

To quote: "Animation values always take precedence over local values, setters and triggers"